# Firefox doesn't show images

Tags: firefox, dojo.gridx, gridx

We have a gridx with various span tag linked to a css with images.

HTML in gridx:

```
<span class="icon active"/>
```

CSS:

```
.icon.active{
   content:url(../imgs/attivo.png);
   height: 16px;
}
```

The problem is that with Firefox it loads the images (we can see it with firebug) but we can't see them. In all the other browsers it works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.icon.active::after`

```css
.icon.active::after{
   content:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=i&w=26&h=26');
   height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table"><span class="icon active"></span></div>
<div class="table"><span class="icon active"></span></div>
<div class="table"><span class="icon active"></span></div>
<div class="table"><span class="icon active"></span></div>
```

OR background-image:

```css
.icon.active {
  background: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=Q&w=26&h=26') no-repeat;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="table"><span class="icon active"></span></div>
<div class="table"><span class="icon active"></span></div>
<div class="table"><span class="icon active"></span></div>
<div class="table"><span class="icon active"></span></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
class="Haldocompose"
```

Link to Docs:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/10i5agK1Ot1eiB_R5JVEVHY41B0rEvjVyeQ1rl50DTdY/edit

Comment: Post the documentation plz

Comment: Thnx alex. Ez fix.